# spark standalone cluster, job running on one executor

Tags: apache-spark

I have a small cluster of 3 nodes with 12 total cores and 44 GB of memory. I am reading a small text file from hdfs (5 mb ) and running kmeans algorithm on it. I set the number of executors to 3 and partitioned my text file into three partitions. The application UI shows that only one of the executors is running all the tasks. 
Here is the screenshot of the application GUI[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gewMG.png)
And here is the Jobs UI:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THT8P.png)
Can somebody help me figure out why my tasks are all running in one executor while others are idle? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using such a heavy software stack for not so big data and small cluster?

Comment: I just want to test to see if my spark code is running correctly on a small subset of the data and then run it on a bigger data.

Comment: I am actually running a variation of kmeans for research. I just want to test to see if my spark code is running correctly on a small subset of the data and then run it on a bigger data. I could not understand why my application was creating so many jobs. But now that I think more about it I think my algorithm never converges and hence causes spark to create so many small jobs. Because the job is too small, it is running the job on one executor only. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to re-partition your file into 12 partitions. If you have 3 partitions and each node has 4 cores it's enough no run all tasks on 1 node. Spark roughly splits the work as 1 partition on 1 core.